# linux sockets only reciving first chunk of data

Tags: c++, linux, sockets

I have two programs, on is server and only listening and the client is talking. I send 1mbytes of data in chunks of 64bytes each. I will get the first chunk of 64byte but then my server exits because it failed to get other data. My client is sending all of the data.

```
void ServerLinux::Receive(){

    int sock = 0;
    struct sockaddr_in server;
    char buffer[this->packageLength];

    if ((sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)) < 0) {
        this->Die("Failed to create socket");
    }

    memset(&server, 0, sizeof(server));
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    server.sin_port = htons(this->port);

    if(bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &server, sizeof(server)) < 0){
        this->Die("Failed to bind the server socket");
    }
    if(listen(sock, 1) < 0){
        this->Die("Failed to listen on server socket");
    }

    int clientSocket = 0;
    struct sockaddr_in client;
    socklen_t size = sizeof(client);
    if((clientSocket = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &client, &size)) < 0){
        this->Die("Failed to accept client");
    }

    int received = -1;

    //This is fine data is recived
    if((received = recv(clientSocket, buffer, this->packageLength,0)) < 0){
        this->Die("Failed to receive initial bytes from client");
    }
    std::cout << "Received!" << std::endl;

    //Data is not received in this while loop
    while(received > 0){
        if((received = recv(sock, buffer, this->packageLength,0)) < 0){
            this->Die("Failed to receive additional bytes frin client");
        }
        std::cout << "Received!" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use the same arguments for recv?

works: recv(**clientSocket**, buffer, this->packageLength,0)

doesn't work recv(**sock**, buffer, this->packageLength,0)

Change sock to **clientSocket**.

Comment: Also, learn to love to check the actual error returned from function by analyzing ERRNO.

Comment: This might be a good occasion to suggest a `do { ... } while (...);` loop to avoid code duplication.

Comment: Well, that was actually kind of awkward

@SergeyA I can't belive that they haven't thought us this at university. Thanks, good to know.

Comment: @Olof, judging from personal experience, they will not teach you anything good computer-science wise in the university. Everytime they do, it is a very lucky exception. You see, really good programmers are seldom computer science teachers for multiple reasons.

Comment: Other than the error message, the first socket function is not needed. Set received > 0 before while and it will work fine. No need for do...while